# spring.net long load times and alternatives to it

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

Until recently I have been working on an application made with spring.net and nhibernate 2.3. The problem with it was that after building it it took about 15 minutes for it to load(for the page in the browser to actually load). To make it bun faster I would go inside the web.xml file and comment out pages and controls I didn't need. This got the time down to about 4 minutes but still this kinda sucks and you can imagine the problems this lead to when working alongside a lot of other developers using Subversion.

My questions are:
Why was this happening?
Is there any other Ioc/dependency injection framework for .net that doesn't have this problem?

Comment: how many objects are you creating?

Answer (score 0):

you can mark your objects with lazy-init, so they will be resolved the first time they are called.
the default is 'false' but you can change it by defining the 'default-lazy-init=true' in your objects node, like:`<objects default-lazy-init="true">`

You can use this mode in development, and setting it to the default value when going into testing/production (so you ensure at load time that nothing is broken in the config)

Comment: tried it, still takes a long time to work, only goes faster if I exclude my pages from the sollutions :(

Comment: maybe you can plugin a tracer and see where is most of the time being lost? Jetbrain's dottrace is nice and it has a 10 day evaluation period